# not able to access Postgres container in docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml with two services, a custom image (the service called code) and a Postgres server. Below I attach the Dockerfile to built the image called `app` of the first service and next the docker-compose.yml:

```
 # Dockerfile of custom image

 FROM ubuntu:latest

 RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
   && cd /usr/local/bin \
   && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
   && pip3 install --upgrade pip

 WORKDIR /usr/app

 COPY ./* ${PWD}/

 ADD ./requirements.txt ./
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD ./ ./


 # docker-compose.yml
 version: '3.2'

 services:

   code:
     image: app:latest
     ports:
      - 5001:5001
     networks:
       - docker-elk_elk

   postgres:
     image: postgres:9.5-alpine
     environment:
       POSTGRES_USER: postgres     # define credentials
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres # define credentials
       POSTGRES_DB: postgres       # define database
     ports:
      - 5432:5432            # Postgres port
     networks:
       - docker-elk_elk

 networks:
    docker-elk_elk:
            external: true
```

Also here `docker-elk_elk` points to another network where another docker-compose stack runs and I want the above docker-compose to join too. However when I run `docker-compose run code bash` and obtain a shell in `code` service, a `curl https://postgres:5432` gives the following message : `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to postgres:5432`. I've tried also `curl http://postgres:5432` which returned `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. Furthermore, the `docker-elk_elk` network (clearly created by elasticsearch-logtash-kibaba stack) when doing  `docker network ls` gives

```
  NETWORK ID          NAME                            DRIVER              SCOPE
  8a54fe394fe8        docker-elk_elk                  bridge              local
```

I'm really lost and confused, can someone help me out? If there is any piece of info that might be necessary or helpful and wasn't included above let me know please.

I forgot to mention that `app` is just a simple python application (not a web app or other python sophisticated libraries).

P.S. Something that perhaps I should have mentioned above. What I want to do, is using the ubuntu container with the app inside to query (and send data) both to the postgres and Elasticsearch (which is in the other docker-compose stack) db.

Comment: you can't run the command `curl https://postgres:5432` because you are not configuring postgres with SSL certificates, you should run `ping postgres` command in the shell to test its connectivity.

Comment: You cannot curl a Postgres server and port. You can use a Postgres client for that - like psql: `psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres` or `docker-compose exec postgres psql`

Comment: @Ma'mounothman thank you for the prompt response. Ping must be run in the postgres container right? So I should do a `docker-compose run postgres bash` (for example) and do a `ping postgres`? What will happen in that case?

Comment: what to include so that I can do a `curl https://postgres:5432`? What I want is to be able in the container with the app, to query the postgres container using python.

Comment: PostgreSQL is a database server, not a Web server.  You can't use `curl` with it because it's the wrong kind of client.  Skip all of these parts with getting a debugging `bash` or sending ICMP packets to the container: can you correctly configure your application code using a Python database library to talk to the database?

Comment: no ping should be performed from `code` container, after you run `docker-compose run code bash`, you might not be able to run ping if its not installed on your container, just after you login to `code` container  run `apt-get install iputils-ping` if ping is not available, then remove it by running `apt-get remove iputils-ping`

Comment: @DavidMaze I can configure the app code and I understand your point. I thought that postgres will expose an api upon creation allowing requests. I don't understand your suggestion though tbh. How should I change the app configuration to send data to postgres?